# How do i insert correctly retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

When I try to insert retrofit dependencies it shows an error of too much expressions in a single line of code. But it's just the same dependency that is written in the Retrofit web page.

I try to write them in parenthesis and double quotes but they do not get downloaded.

[image: Screenshot of build log]

Comment: Did you try it like this: implementation("path.to.dependency:version_number")?

Comment: You must be writing it inside the double quotes and parenthesis as well, if it doesn't work then you can change the versions.

Comment: [Please include your `build.gradle.kts` as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)